# How do I make a rule that deletes a node when it hasn't been viewed for "X" amount of time?

Tags: 7, rules

Im on d7. I what to delete nodes that are no longer "pertinent" on my site. I figure the best way to do tho would be with rules scheduler, but if anyone has any other suggestions, I would be open to them.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a flag and use rules to flag the page whenever it is viewed. Then add "node has flagging count" condition to your "delete rule" to check if it has less than the amount of views you want and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

I am unfamiliar with any current modules that accomplish this. D7's default structure does not store last_accessed or similar statistics outside the watchdog, which would be complex to parse and use.

IMHO accomplishing this goal would involve creating a custom module that :

1. Adds a field to store a 'last accessed' field linked to your nodes.
2. Hooks into [hook_node_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) to update this field each time a node
   is viewed
3. Hooks into [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7) to conditionally select any nodes with
   viewed age greater than your maximum. Call node_delete for each. You could also set $node->status=0 and archive the content without deleting it.

Optionally, you could also add an admin dialog through hook_menu that set a variable defining the maximium unviewed age of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable and configure the core [Statstics](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/statistics) module, page accesses will get logged in the `{accesslog}` table.  One of the columns is `timestamp`, which logs when a path was accessed.

I am unaware if you can integrate Statics into rules, but you could make a custom [hook_cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_cron/7), query `{accesslog}`, check the `timestamp`, and then act appropriately.  Just note that paths are logged, not nids.

Personally, I would unpublish the nodes rather than delete them.  Also, the Statistics module can be a real performance hog.